# SQL Interval Query

Tags: sql, sql-server

Working on writing a SQL Query that would group the time based on a 15 minute interval. So example is if the transaction occurs at 08:09, i want that to be the within the range of 08:00 - 08:15 and so on.

I'm honestly not sure how to go about pulling the interval based on the start time (CDR_CALLS.STARTDATETIME) of the call

```
Select CASE when CDR_CALLS.DN = '9370' then ‘Location 1’
            when CDR_CALLS.DN = '9371' then ‘Location 2’
            when CDR_CALLS.DN  = '9372' then ‘Location 3’
            when CDR_CALLS.DN = '9373' then ‘Location 4’
            when CDR_CALLS.DN  = '9374' then ‘Location 5
            when CDR_CALLS.DN = '9375' then ‘Location 6’
            when CDR_CALLS.DN  = '9376' then ‘Location 7’
            when CDR_CALLS.DN = '9377' then ‘Location 8’
            when CDR_CALLS.DN = '9378' then ‘Location 9’
            when CDR_CALLS.DN = '9379' then ‘Location 10’
            else ‘No Location Defined’ 
       END AS TRANSFER_TO,
       CDR_CALLS.DNIS,
       CDR_CALLS.ANI,
       CDR_CALLS.LANG,
       CDR_CALLS.CDR_LAST_MENU,
       CDR_CALLS.ROUTE_CODE,
       CDR_CALLS.CDR_END_CODE,
       CDR_CALLS.STARTDATETIME, 
       CONVERT(char(10),CDR_CALLS.STARTDATETIME,101) as Date,
       CONVERT(char(20),CDR_CALLS.STARTDATETIME,108) as Interval_Time,
       CDR_CALLS.ENDDATETIME, 
       CDR_MENU_OPTION_DESC.MENU_ID,
       CDR_MENU_OPTION_DESC.OPTION_ID,
       CDR_MENU_OPTION_DESC.MENU_OPTION_DESC
from CDR_CALLS
FULL OUTER JOIN CDR_MENU_OPTION_DESC ON CDR_CALLS.CLIENT_ID = CDR_MENU_OPTION_DESC.CLIENT_ID
where OPTION_ID = '8'
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (When it comes to date/time many products are far from ANSI SQL compliant.)

Comment: Sample data and expected results would be useful here.

Comment: I'm using MS SQL 2005. The expected output would essentially show a result of
TRANSFER_TO, CALLS.DNIS,LAST_MENU, OPTION_ID, Date, Interval. Where the interval would be within a 15 minute range.

Essentially, when i run the query, i want it to provide reports for
00:00
00:15
00:30
00:45
01:00
etc.

Comment: Right now, when i run the query, i am getting all expected report with the exception for being able to get the Interval. The STARTDATETIME is currently formatted as '2019-03-23 08:03:53' Which is why i am using  CDR_CALLS.STARTDATETIME, 
CONVERT(char(10),CDR_CALLS.STARTDATETIME,101) as Date,
CONVERT(char(20),CDR_CALLS.STARTDATETIME,108) as Interval_Time to pull the current time. But not sure how i can use the CDR_CALLS.STARTDATETIME,108) as Interval_Time to break out the 15 minute intervals

Comment: Are you *sure* you're using SQL Server 2005? Apart from the fact that 2005 has been out of support for several year, SQL Server also does not use backticks (`\` `) to delimit identify.

Comment: I'm able to get it to work now using DATEADD(MINUTE,(DATEPART(MINUTE, STARTDATETIME) / 30)*30,(DATEADD(HOUR, DATEDIFF(HOUR, 0, STARTDATETIME), 0))) as Time_Interval,

Answer (score 0):

You can take the number of minutes since 1/1/1900 and integer divide it by 15 to get 15 minute intervals.

```
group by datediff(minute,'1900-01-01',CDR_CALLS.STARTDATETIME)/15
```

Comment: When i try that, i get this error "Invalid Query. Check the syntax. Column 'CDR_CALLS.TRANSFER_TO' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause."

Comment: If you're grouping, then you need to aggregate everything else.  https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp